# Programa para facturas en Java, con menu de opciones. No GUI

Tags: java

Esta es la primera vez que tomo clases de java (o de programación en general). Estoy atorado con lo siguiente; me piden un programa para controlar las facturas de una empresa que vende productos por litro. Debo presentar un menu de opciones para dar entrada a los datos, presentar los datos por pantalla y una opción para mostrar el total de las facturas procesadas.

Los datos de cada factura son: código de producto, descripción de producto, cantidad del producto, precio del producto y total a pagar.

El programa debe correr hasta que el cliente desee salir y debe ser creado con métodos, estructuras cíclicas y estructuras selectivas.

Hasta el momento esto es lo que tengo:

```
package facturacion;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Facturacion {


    // constructor 
  private String codigoProducto;
   private String descripcionProducto;
  private double cantidadComprada;
  private double precioporLitro;


  public Facturacion (String codigo, String descripcion, double cantidad, 
double precio)
{
      codigoProducto = codigo;
      descripcionProducto = descripcion;
      cantidadComprada = cantidad;
      precioporLitro = precio;
}
  public void setcodigoProducto (String codigo)
  {
      codigoProducto = codigo;
  }
  public String getcodigoProducto()
  {
      return codigoProducto;
  }
  public void setdescripcionProducto (String descripcion)
  {
      descripcionProducto = descripcion;
  }
  public String getdescripcionProducto()
  {
      return descripcionProducto;
  }
  public void setCantidadComprada (double cantidad)
  {
   cantidadComprada = cantidad;
  }
  public double getCantidadComprada()
  {
      return cantidadComprada;
  }
public void setprecioporLitro (double precio){
      precioporLitro = precio;
   }
public double getprecioporLitro()
{
    return precioporLitro;
}
 public double getTotalFactura()
 {
 double calculodelmontoTotal;
 calculodelmontoTotal = cantidadComprada * precioporLitro;
 return calculodelmontoTotal;
 }   
 public static void main (String args [])
{
String codigo, descripcion;
double cantidad, precio;
Facturacion factura = new Facturacion ("","",0,0.0);
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Porporcione el codigo del producto: ");
        codigo = input.nextLine();
factura.setcodigoProducto(codigo);

System.out.println("Porporcione la descripcion del producto: ");
        descripcion = input.nextLine();
factura.setdescripcionProducto(descripcion);

System.out.println("Ingrese el precio por litro: ");
        precio = input.nextDouble();
factura.setprecioporLitro(precio);

System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad a comprar del producto: ");
        cantidad = input.nextDouble();
factura.setCantidadComprada(cantidad);

factura.getTotalFactura();
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("\n Codigo del producto: %s", 
factura.getcodigoProducto());
System.out.printf("\n Descripcion del producto: %s", 
factura.getdescripcionProducto());
System.out.printf("\n Precio por litro: %s", factura.getprecioporLitro());
System.out.printf("\n Cantidad en litros: %s", 
factura.getCantidadComprada());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf(" El total de la factura es: $%.2f\n", 
 factura.getTotalFactura());
    }
 }
```

Como se puede ver, he logrado que se pida la entrada de datos, el calculo del total de la factura y la salida de datos por pantalla. Me falta el método para el menu de opciones, las estructuras condicionales, métodos para el acumulador de totales, el gran total y la opción de salir o continuar.

Se agradece cualquier ayuda que pueda darme.

Comment: La idea es que despliegues el menu de opciones, digamos con un numero asignado para cada opcion.  Por lo que se ve tienes 3 opciones mas una cuarta para salir.  Lo que debes hacer es crear este menu de opciones y escuchar por la seleccion del cliente.  Esto debe de estar dentro de un loop que se repita hasta que el usuario selecciona la cuarta opcion.

Comment: Debes hacer uso de un `do-while` para que tu programa corra al menos una vez y lo siga haciendo hasta que el usuario quiera salir. Las opciones puedes presentarlas por pantalla (ej: 1. para esto, 2. para lo otro, etc..) y con un `switch` evaluar la opción y ejecutar todo el código deseado.

Comment: Estoy creando el menu y las opciones, así como el case / switch. cada uno de ellos va a llamar un método. Creo que las dos partes donde se da entrada a los datos y donde se muestran, pueden ser dos métodos distintos, pero no se como convertir el código de ambos (se encuentra en el post original) a metodos, y luego como llamarlos con cada opcion